# Cant display images in Listview from database mysql in c#

Tags: c#, listview

I couldn't display the images from my database in Listview although I can retrieve some data like my the title of it.

Check out my code:

```
public void LoadBooks()
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        listView1.Clear();
        ImageList myImageList1 = new ImageList();
        myImageList1.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 80);
        listView1.LargeImageList = myImageList1;


        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from booktable";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Rows)
        {
            byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])dr["bookphoto"];
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
            Image bookimages= Image.FromStream(stream);
            myImageList1.Images.Add(bookimages);


            ListViewItem lsvparent = new ListViewItem();
            lsvparent.Text = dr["booktitle"].ToString();

            listView1.Items.Add(lsvparent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Although the size of the image is showing in the Listview but there is any image just a blank image.

Hope you help me . Thank you

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside foreach, do you get anything inside byteBLOBData variable?

Comment: Yes it has a data which is the picture that i add into the database.

Comment: Not the answer, but you can replace `ListViewItem lsvparent = new ListViewItem();
                    lsvparent.Text = dr["booktitle"].ToString();

                    listView1.Items.Add(lsvparent);` with `listView1.Items.Add(dr["booktitle"].ToString());`

Comment: @MaryJhealynVillena ok, is the Image object being created? So you can tell if the problem is with appending it to ImageList or downloading image from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you set the `IamgeIndex` that points to the `ImageList`.

It is a property of the `ListViewItem` and you can set it when adding it  or at any time later on.

This will set it to the latest image in the list:

```
listView1.Items.Add(lsvparent, myImageList1.Image.Count - 1);
```

To change it later you can use:

```
listView1.Items[23].ImageIndex = 42;
```

or, if you have nice names:

```
listView1.Items[lsvparent].ImageIndex = 0;
```

Note that any `ImageList` is restricted to one `Size`, a  maximum of 256x256 pixels and one bit depth fo all images!

It is a good idea to load a default image as the first one into the `ImageList` i.e. at index = 0 so you have a common one to fall back to.